# Escaping escaped quote in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, escaping, mariadb

I have a field containing the text "test \'test"
when I want to select the data of this row based on this field I must do :

```
select * from test where field like '%test \\\\\'test%';
```

why 5 "\" instead of 3 ? and how can I get this string from the original text using a PHP function like  addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string ?

> (10.0.16-MariaDB ; PHP 5.3.3 , Centos 6.5)

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: echo mysql_real_escape_string("test \'test")  ==> "test \\\'test" , this is the result I get, in SQL it only works with 5*\

Answer (score 0):

one \ is used to escape ' another two are used to escape two more \ (therefore five of them).
so your php send to database three \ and ' `(\\\')`, your db then use one \ to escape second \ and third is used to escape '. In the final there is \' (as you needed)

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string("test \'test")
```

will output `"test \\\'test"` because function see this: `"test 'test"` (without backslas, because baskslash was eaten by php to parse string). So mysql_real_escape_strings output is incorrect, because your string input is incorrect.

Comment: anyway I recommend to use prepare statements and forget about mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: so how can I get "test \\\\\'test" from "test \'test"

Comment: it's the opposit way. you get "test \'test" from "test \\\\\'test". First, you put "test \\\\\'test" somewhere in your php code. php parse this string and escape some characters, so it's output is "test \\\'test" - this is what is send to your database. Your database receive this string and parse it (and of course, escape characters), so database engine get (and use) string "test \'test"

Comment: when you put "test \'test" to function mysql_real_escape_string, php first parse your string and escape characters. so  mysql_real_escape_string function receive "test 'test". Therefore output of mysql_real_escape_string is NOT what you expected

Comment: no, I am wrong about mysql_real_escape_string. mysql_real_escape_string gets "test \'test" but it don't know, you want this particular string, it assumes you want escape ' with that only backslash. so it escape in the way that at the end database engine have "test 'test"

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but what I need: 1/ field in data base :"test \'test";2/ user input in a form: "test \'test"; 2/ run query "select * from test where field like '%test \\\\\'test%';"

Comment: as i mentioned, i recommend you to use prepare statement. therefore string value is send as argument (not as part of query), you don't need escape any characters, and it's also safer in my opinion.